# InflateException Caused by <fragment> Tag Without a Bound Class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the classes and xml layouts of the Master-Detail flow, which is available when creating a new project, to have a list and a detail view side-by-side. However, I am getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TrueFalse/com.TrueFalse.news.NewsModule}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1777)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at com.TrueFalse.news.NewsModule.onCreate(NewsModule.java:19)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(  724): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:390)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:538)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(  724):    ... 20 more
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that I am not setting either android:name="" or class="", which would explain the stack trace, but the template, mentioned above, had this same xml file apart from changing around some names.

The line number in the trace for my code is

```
setContentView(R.layout.news_list_container);
```

My NewsModule class extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.

---

/res/values-large/refs.xml (maps news_list_container.xml to news_twopane_container.xml, which I am fairly sure this happens, because it works fine on devices that don't satisfy the "large: constraint.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- List of layout overrides for screens that can support iPad style views.
         This should mirror the other refs.xml file-->
    <item name="news_list_container" type="layout">@layout/news_twopane_container</item>
</resources>
```

/res/layout/news_twopane_container.xml (line 14 is the beginning of the second fragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/news_list_container"
        android:name="com.TrueFalse.news.NewsList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/news_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the `Fragment` related codes?

Comment: You called `setContentView(R.layout.news_list_container);`, can you show this xml file to us?

Comment: What if you added "android:name="com.TrueFalse.news.DetailsFrgmt", would that work? I'm just asking because I have the same problem, and although your answer fixed the problem, I don't understand why our first approach isn't working

Comment: I used my answer because I wanted the details fragment to be blank at the very beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was using the template, I overlooked the fact that the second fragment should actually be a *placeholder* for a fragment, which in the template was a FrameLayout. My original suspicion turned out to be the issue because a fragment *must* have a class associated with it. so /res/news_twopane_container.xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/news_list_container"
        android:name="com.TrueFalse.news.NewsList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- NOT fragment, because we don't have data to put here yet -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/news_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this by replacing onCreate method with onCreateView. I think this might help for you.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Loading Container with news_container.xml");
        setContentView(R.layout.news_list_container);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_container, container, false);
}
```

Comment: That function isn't overridable in FragmentActivity and I already have inflation code for both fragments.

Comment: Interesting! why do you think that its not overridable? I already tested my suggestion above and that seems to work atleast for me!

Comment: If you highlight `FragmentActivity` and press F4 in eclipse, the type hierarchy shows that the only onCreateView function is implemented with (String, Context, AttributeSet) is implemented for that class. I do realize that the Fragment class has this method-argument pair, but that is not what the news_twopane_container.xml was meant for.